# PostgreSQL-like returning modification statement piping/use in CTEs in MariaDB/MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, mariadb, sql-insert

Trying to find a non-convoluted way to pipe/chain returning modification statements (ex. `insert .. returning ..`) in MariaDB/MySQL. This is valid PostgreSQL code:

Create 2 tables:

```
create table test1(
    id serial primary key,
    value int
);

create table test2(
    ref_id int,
    value varchar
);
```

Using `with`, pipe the output of `insert .. returning ..` into another `insert`:

```
with
    cte as (
        insert into test1(value)
            select floor(random()*10) as value
        returning *
    )
insert into test2(ref_id, value)
    select
            id,
            concat('Inserted value is ', value::varchar) as value
        from cte
;
```

**Edit**: The example inserts only one row for simplicity, but the general use case would be inserting multiple (usually at least thousands of) rows. To simulate a real-world use case, add `from generate_series(1,1000000)` to the `select`.

Test returns (1, 4) from `test1` (chosen by fair dice roll), and (1, 'Inserted value is 4') from `test2` (note that the 1 in `test2` is dynamically generated by `test1`'s serial/autoincrement beforehand, it can't be specified as a literal).

This can be pretty useful when one needs to modify data in separate tables which is logically connected in some way (ex. inserting a value, returning a serial/autoincrement id, then inserting that id as a reference into some other table). I'd commonly chain a dozen inserts and updates that way in PostgreSQL:

```
with
    cte1 as (insert .. returning ..),
    cte2 as (update .. from cte1 .. returning ..),
    cte3 as (delete .. from cte2 .. returning ..)
...
```

However, `with` seems to be restricted to `select` CTEs in MariaDB, so one is essentially limited to one modification statement at a time and no way to pipe `insert .. returning ..` into further statements (and no, subqueries don't work either).
Is there a way to accomplish this without an external tool (like storing the return value through PHP and then issuing further statements, which can have horrible performance if the query is processing thousands or millions of rows)?

Keep in mind that there might not be a guaranteed way to correctly select the inserted rows later (esp. with constant writes to the table) if there is no strictly unique key for the inserted rows, so using the output of `insert .. returning ..` is pretty much mandatory in my use case.

#### Potential solutions looked into so far

- `insert .. returning ..` (MariaDB 10.5+) returns the ID but doesn't work as a CTE or subquery. I also can't find a way to store that resultset into a temporary table or variable, which would easily solve the problem through subsequent statements referencing the temporary table(s).

Comment: 3 years later and am running into the same issue.  Really disappointed to see that MariaDB hasn't updated the capabilities of the returning statement in this time.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL/MariaDB does not support `returning` or the-like, so you have to run multiple statements here.

You can, however, use `last_insert_id()` to recover the last auto-generated value, so you can do something like:

```
insert into test1(value) 
values (floor(rand() * 10));

insert into test2 (ref_id, value) 
select id, value
from test1
where id = last_insert_id();
```

Comment: Also only SELECT is allowed in CTE.

Comment: That works if processing the rows one by one, but would take hours instead of seconds to complete if one has to insert a larger number of rows.
Also, `returning` is supported in MariaDB 10.5 onwards, but is severely limited compared to PostgreSQL's implementation.

Comment: @MunyuShizumi I think that there is no general solution now. Look for solutions to each specific problem separately. Be ready that even the principles used for two separate problems solvings to be optimal may differ.

Comment: @MunyuShizumi: agree with Akina, there is no generic solution. The above works for the first example given in your question. Depending on the actual use case, another type of logic might be needed (although the base idea remains, that you need to split the operation in at least two statements).